# Rails: How to change the text on the submit button in a Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have listed my _form.html.erb file below what i would like to do is change the text on the submit button i know how to do it in html but not shure how to do it in Rails 3

```
%= form_for(@faq) do |f| %>
  <% if @faq.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@faq.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this faq from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @faq.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :question %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :answer %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :answer %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

instead of

```
<%= f.submit  %>
```

put

```
<%= f.submit "My Submit Text" %>
```

Comment: OMG i cant believe i was so dang close i was trying to use it like HTML name="My Submit Text" thanks this got me what i was looking for :)

Comment: I can't believe this very simple thing isn't in the fricking [API docs for this method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit).

Comment: This didn't work for me -- I had to do `<%= f.submit :value => "Login" %>` instead. (Rails 3.2.11)

Comment: If you want to keep the button style, you can do: f.button :submit, "My Submit Text"

Comment: It's worth reading the other answers that show how to make changes using a file such as  `config/locales/en.yml`

Answer (score 65):

If you want to change all create and update form submit tags, this change is easy to make. Modify `config/locales/en.yml` like so:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Crear un %{model}"
      update: "Confirmar cambios al %{model} creado"
```

Comment: I like how you put Spanish phrases in the English locale!

Comment: I wanted to edit this answer, but I would rather let people come here, and smile(until they hit a new bug).

Answer (score 45):

Building on @daniel's answer, you can also customize submit tag values on a **per-model basis**:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      model_name:
        create: "Create"
        update: "Update"
```

And then in your form you can just use:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

---

See [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit) for the documentation (second example.)

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
<%= f.submit 'Name of the submit button' %>
```

For questions like this, consider using the available docs either at

- [Ruby on Rails API website](http://api.rubyonrails.org)
- [APIdock Ruby on Rails section](http://apidock.com/rails) (very easy navigation / search)

Sometimes, a google search like the one below helps:

- Google: [site:api.rubyonrails.org f.submit](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aapi.rubyonrails.org+f.submit)

Comment: its just so much easier asking here than trying to read them docs with no examples!

Comment: I find the Ruby docs to be very frustrating when it comes to answering specific how-do-I-do-xxx questions.

Answer (score 8):

When writing in  **erb**

`<%= f.submit "your text" %>`

when writing in **HAML**

```
= f.button :submit, "your text"
```

In **HAML** comma should be there after submit otherwise it will throw error.

Comment: Comma doesn't have to be there, works for me without.

Comment: Yeah, you are right in haml comma is required.
= f.button :submit, "your text"

Comment: Using a comma throws an error for me (and it works fine without one) on rails 4 (no haml).

Comment: @naomisorbet yes, that's why I have corrected it in my 2 comment. Please check.

Comment: @pulkit21 I saw it, thank you, but I wanted to clarify that the comma throws an error in rails without haml.

Comment: Yes. I looked at the first answer and it threw an error. I simply added the comma like you said and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I only had to translate the model name this way:

```
pt-br:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        one: "Usuário"
        more: "Usuários"
```

This also would complement @daniel's answer which gave me the hint what was missing. However, I suppose that @daniel's answer is not really necessary as it is already on [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using helpers is not acceptable because of used text or you need additionally add class etc., so you can directly override `value`:

```
<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary', value: 'Login' %>
```

or:

```
<%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary', value: 'Login' %>
```

By the way it was mentioned by **@cassi.lup** in comment to accepted answer.

Tested on Rails 4.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, I was trying with this scenario:

```
f.submit t('conf.begin') class: 'btn btn-outline btn-success'
```

But it was not working, the solution was with a comma before the class (it was not obvious at the begining for me):

```
f.submit t('conf.begin'), class: 'btn btn-outline btn-success'
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

for Slim version use
value="xyz"
to change the default submit input text.

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, use

```
<%= f.submit 'Desired text on the button' %>
```