# Rails change submit button text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Any way to change the default text for a submit button?

For example, the following submit button for the `user` model and the `update` action will have a button value of `Update User`

`<%= f.submit %>`

Is there something I can add to the tag to make it, `Save`, for example?

Or am I going to have to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Should be:

```
<%= f.submit "Save" %>
```

Comment: I'm honestly embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: [Also see this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag). Though it's the `_tag` variant, the options work for `f.` variants as well. Same for other form helpers.

Comment: Consider using en.yml file - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769483/rails-3-form-how-to-change-the-text-on-the-submit-button

Comment: ```<%= f.submit :Save %>``` This works too :)

Answer (score 5):

I came across this thread looking for a way to change the value for `f.button :submit`, not `f.submit`. The reason I'm using `f.button :submit` is because I'm using bootstrap to style the button, and the `class: "btn btn-primary"` argument needs to be passed to the .button method. Anyways, I couldn't find any documentation on it, so I messed around a bit and found the solution.

At first I tried <%= f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %> but it gave me an error saying I was passing 3 arguments when there should only be 2, which is what I expected.

So here's what solved the problem:

```
<%= f.button :submit => "", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

This made the button text what I wanted "Create Article". Before, when I just had `f.button :submit`, the button text was "submit", which I'm guessing was pulled from the symbol and converted into a string. Can anyone explain why passing an empty hash value did the trick?

Comment: You can do this with `f.submit` such as `<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for rails > 6.1.0:

```
<%= form.submit "Custom button", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: It is also working for rails 5.2