# Changing simple_form submit button i18n text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-i18n

This is my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:backend, @department] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :parentid, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }  %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is my form and I want to change the submit text, now the text is `create department`, so I tried:

```
zh-CN:
  simple_form:
    helpers:
      submit:
        department:
          create: "新建部门"
          update: "保存编辑"
```

but nothing changed. How can I change it?

Comment: @ramedju thank you :)

Comment: Are you overriding  button labels for submit?

Comment: yes, i want different model have different button name

Comment: Maybe you can try to vidit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769483/rails-3-form-how-to-change-the-text-on-the-submit-button just give it a try. If it doesn't work, just tell me.

Comment: @ramedju I find a  gem `i18n-debug` , it can dispaly all infomation in log. I might be able to solve the problem。

Comment: @ramedju Thank you very much。

Comment: Then that would be great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I add a gem `i18n-debug`, then I restart server and flash the page. Look the terminal log , I know what is the problem。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2IkG.jpg)
so, after `zh-CN` is `helpers`, not `simple_form`

Answer (score 0):

Bruce Wayne give excellent answer. 
But I'v got error  in i18n-debug:

> private method `prepend' called for I18n::Backend::Simple:Class
>   (NoMethodError)

on **debug.rb**

I changed

```
Backend::Simple.prepend(Debug::Hook)
```

on

```
Backend::Simple.send :prepend, Debug::Hook
```

and it works fine!

Or you can use patched gem in your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'i18n-debug', github: 'robotex82/i18n-debug', branch: 'robotex82-patch-1'
```

from https://github.com/robotex82/i18n-debug/tree/robotex82-patch-1

Answer (score 0):

[i18n_debug_page](https://github.com/yfractal/i18n_debug_page) provides a UI for i18n debug info, it looks like as below:

[image]