# Use custom name in auto-rendered HTML in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Assume I have a model like this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And in `items#new` or `items#edit`, in `app/views/items/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

This will generate a submit button named "Create Item" or "Update Item" depending on the route.

Now I want to use an alternative name for the generated button text (and only here!), like "Create Article" and "Update Article", while keeping the name `Item` everywhere else in the code, so I can still use `items_url`, `ItemsHelper::some_method` etc.

Using `<%= f.submit "Text" %>` is not an option since it won't keep the difference between `Create %{model}` and `Update %{model}` when the same form is rendered in different views.

I have made the following attempts without success:

```
# 1 - no difference observed
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  def display_name
    "Object"
  end
end

# 2 - undefined method `name' for "Artlcle":String
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  def model_name
    "Object"
  end
end

# 3 - undefined method `object_path'
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  def model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new Item, nil, 'Object'
  end
end
```

This isn't a good solution, either, as it defeats Rails' DRY principle.

```
<% if determine_controller %>
  <%= f.submit "Some text" %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.submit "Some other text" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I achieve this goal? Is it possible without `rails-i18n`?

Additional question: Does the solution in your answer also work on Rails 5?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `<%= f.submit "My Submit Text" %>` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769483/rails-how-to-change-the-text-on-the-submit-button-in-a-rails-form)

Comment: @lacostenycoder That would *not* retain the difference between `Create %{model}` and `Update %{model}`.

Comment: would it kill you to do this with javascript?

Comment: @lacostenycoder There are much better workarounds than using JS.

Comment: @AbM The code you linked clearly shows `object.model_name.human`, which in my case is ``undefined method `name' for "Artlcle":String``.

Comment: I agree that it could be much easier to accomplish that with erb, but to answer your question, can you try changing the `model_name` method to `ActiveModel::Name.new(Item, nil, 'Object')` instead of just `"Object"`

Comment: @AbM The exception is now ``undefined method `object_path'``. No luck.

Comment: @iBug yes, this is the expected behaviour based on [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/186115180e671e1a222f368600189df155446260/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L179). If you change the name, it will change the routes, I18n keys,  routes naming, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit too hackish, but monkey-patching does the job (thanks to [@AbM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2697183/abm) for a link to Rails source):

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  def model_name.human
    'Article'
  end
end
```

To make life easier, I wrote a "helper method" in the base class:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.display_name(name)
    self.model_name.define_singleton_method :human do
      name
    end
  end
end
```

And then I could do this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  display_name 'Article'
end
```

Comment: How does the word `Article` get added to your button with this solution?

Comment: Fair enough, but I suppose it wouldn't hurt to use the same name proposed in your question for clarity so that other users may find this question and answer slightly more helpful.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Totally valid! I've updated my answer.